# Default image size parameter for Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I use api request:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

```
/PageName/?fields=id,name,about,picture, ....
```

however, in response picture is always 50px*50px:

```
[picture] => stdClass Object
 (
      [data] => stdClass Object
       (
                    [height] => 50
                    [is_silhouette] => 
                    [url] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/XXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=cefc418b0201572eb9c9ee0c66d81313&oe=5B9CE9E7
                    [width] => 50
        )

 )
```

I dont want to make a separate call for only picture. Is there any way to get larger picture by default?